# Increase the size of an unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on C++ using IAR EMBEDDED WORK BENCH. I am facing a problem while calling a function from `main()`.

My program is used to fetch data from meter through meter protocols.
in my program i have declared an `unsigned char` array of size 255. But the data coming from meter is greater than 255. Are there any possibilities to increase the size of `unsigned char` array? For now I have declared another unsigned character array but it doesn't solve my problem. Also I have gone through this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) but I am unable to get any help. I am stuck to it almost a month, that's why I choose to post my question here to get some help.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Unless the compiler and target platform limits you in one way or another, then yes you can increase the size. The number of elements in an array doesn't have any relation to the element data type. Or you can simply do multiple reads in a loop.

Comment: Never heard of this IAR thing, but is this a freestanding implementation of C++? Do you have full access to the standard library? You cannot increase the size of raw arrays while the program is running, but the standard library offers container types which can change their size.

Answer (score 0):

> in my program i have declared an unsigned char array of size 255
>   I assume you do something like that :

```
char array[255];
```

You won't be able to extend this variable, because it's allocate on the stack.

But you can use the heap:

```
char* array = new char[255];
```

This will be possible to keep your variable and change it's size with another new call (if you want to extend don't forget to copy your old data, and don't forget do delete the old array).

---

Or, **if you can** (don't know that much about your target), just use the STL [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<char> array(255);
```

Same as :

```
std::vector<char> array;
array.reserve(255);
```

This container have some member functions like [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) which will help you (still don't forget to copy your data if you need)

Comment: Some Google research on "IAR embedded" gets one to https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/language-standards/. The information there leads me to the conclusion that the OP does not necessarily use a full-featured C++ implementation, i.e. `std::vector` may not be available to him. Apart from that, dynamic allocation from the free-store tends to be a potential problem in the embedded world anyway.

Comment: I was afraid of that too, because he didn't use it already. I'll edit to be more clear thanks.